# pyspark date_format function returns incorrect year

Tags: python, pyspark, date-format

pyspark.sql.functions.date_format - returns incorrect year for last day of the year

Pyspark Version:  version 2.3.0.cloudera3
Python version : Python 2.7.5

When I try to reformat last date of the year using the function date_format in pyspark, it returns the next year when used with "YYYY" instead of "yyyy".

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *

>>> dftest = spark.createDataFrame([('2017-12-31',)], ['dt'])

>>> dftest.select(date_format('dt', 'MM/dd/yyy').alias('date')).collect()
[Row(date=u'12/31/2017')]
>>> dftest.select(date_format('dt', 'MM/dd/yyyy').alias('date')).collect()
[Row(date=u'12/31/2017')]

>>> dftest.select(date_format('dt', 'MM/dd/YYY').alias('date')).collect()
[Row(date=u'12/31/2018')]
>>> dftest.select(date_format('dt', 'MM/dd/YYYY').alias('date')).collect()
[Row(date=u'12/31/2018')]
```

How is "YYYY" (upper case) different from "yyyy" (lower case)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation on [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.date_format):

*"All pattern letters of the Java class java.text.SimpleDateFormat can be used"*

and if you look in the documentation on java e.g. [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you can see that **uppercase Y refers to the week year** and not the year itself as lowercase y.

With more years than in your example:

```
dftest = spark.createDataFrame([('20{}-12-31'.format(i),) for i in range(19, 25)], ['dt'])
dftest.select('dt', date_format('dt', 'MM/dd/yyyy').alias('date'),
                    date_format('dt', 'MM/dd/YYYY').alias('DATE'),).show()
+----------+----------+----------+
|        dt|      date|      DATE|
+----------+----------+----------+
|2019-12-31|12/31/2019|12/31/2020|
|2020-12-31|12/31/2020|12/31/2021|
|2021-12-31|12/31/2021|12/31/2022|
|2022-12-31|12/31/2022|12/31/2022| # this one is good for both
|2023-12-31|12/31/2023|12/31/2024|
|2024-12-31|12/31/2024|12/31/2025|
+----------+----------+----------+
```

You can see that 2022 is good, and the year ends on a Saturday. If you try more years, you will find the same result when they end on a Saturday. So my guess (not fully sure) is when you use uppercase Y, the parsing  goes to the following Saturday and get the year associated to this Saturday. For 2019, as it is a Tuesday, it jump to Saturday 4th of January 2020 and get this year instead of 2019.